# I am trying to install python and after clicking on install, nothing seems to happen. The set-up page just continues to load. Been waiting since 30min

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I am trying to install python and after clicking on install, nothing seems to happen. The set-up page just continues to load. Been waiting since 30min and nothing seems to happen. I have also installed the right version for my pc. I am trying to install python 3.11.3 64 bit version which is compatible for my pc
Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: What OS, Windows? Are you using the Windows installer or the Microsoft store or? Please [edit] to add details. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.